How to configure titles for workflow runs?
I am trying to configure the name of GitHub Actions workflow runs.
With my ci.yaml file which is triggered on pull requests, it automatically contains the name of the commit that it runs as:

While for other types of triggers (scheduled or manually run), they only contain the name of the action, and there's no mention of the commit at which they were run at:

How can I customize it so that the commit is always visible?

You can add the run-name property to your workflow YAML:
run-name: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_commit.message }}


Although it doesn't seem to work - but it might be an error elsewhere. The main thing is that I'm supposed to use run-name, so I will try that. Thanks!

@Ant The event for the schedule trigger doesn't have a head_commit object, probably.
